# Is it safe to overwrite a .so file or an executable in use using rsync?

Tags: linux, rsync, inode

This is not really a programming question.  We have a large system written in c++ and uses many shared objects (.so) and native executables on Redhat Enterprise Linux.  The system runs on multiple hosts and we use rsync to keep the deployed binaries (shared objects & executables)

If we have to fix a bug in a .so (or executable) we deploy it to a single location and then rsync across all the other hosts

Is it safe to overwrite a .so (or executable) while it is in use (or running)?  I have read that `rm` & `cp` are safe due to how *nix handles `inode` (some sort of reference counting).  But I couldn't find a satisfactory answer when it comes to `rsync`

Comment: If the processes has already loaded the `.so` into memory, it's perfectly safe.

Comment: @OregonTrail, doesn't matter if it's already loaded or not -- even if it's just *opened* but not read from yet, you'll still get to keep your handle on the original inode, preventing its deallocation.

Comment: BTW, for future not-really-programming questions, consider https://unix.stackexchange.com/ (when OS-related), or https://superuser.com/

Comment: ...it wouldn't hurt to understand what an inode *actually is* -- basically, it's the part of the filesystem that actually stores the contents of a file. The important thing to understand is that inodes and directory entries are two different things -- you can have a single inode have multiple directory entries (hardlinks), or *no directory entries at all*. In that last case, it'll be deleted after nobody has that file open, but because of that provisio (waiting for all the preexisting handles to close before deletion actually happens), a file can be safely deleted or replaced while in-use.

Comment: ...now, the bigger problem is that while rsync can safely and atomically replace *just one* executable, it can't replace *multiple* executables as an atomic operation, so you can have a place where only part of the updates are done, and any attempts to restart your service would fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short answer

It's perfectly safe within a single file if you don't use `--in-place`.

It's mostly safe for multiple interdependent files, but has some risks which using `--delay-updates` will minimize.

---

#### Long answer

**By default** (that is, when not using `--in-place`), `rsync` will actually create contents in a new file, named with a temporary name (something like `.__your_file`), and then rename it over the original file when complete.

This rename is a completely atomic operation: Anything trying to open the file will either get the original file, or the replacement (after that replacement is entirely complete).

Moreover, if the original is in use, then its reference count will be nonzero even after the directory entry pointing to it is overwritten with the new entry pointing to the different inode, so the content will remain on-disk (undeleted) until the original file is no longer open.

**However, with multiple files,** you run a risk that only some of those files will be atomically replaced. If you're copying over both a new `foo` and a `libfoo.so` such that the old `foo` won't work with the new `libfoo.so` and the new `foo` won't work with the old `libfoo.so`, you're in a bad situation if you're trying to start an executable after the new `libfoo.so` has been `rename()`'d into place but `foo` hasn't yet.

The nearest thing to a fix for this that rsync has available is the `--delay-updates` option, which will wait until it has *both* `.__foo` and `.__libfoo.so` complete and then rename them both next to each other. There's still no operating-system-level guarantee that you can't see an updated version of one file and not the other, but the time window in which this can occur is made substantially smaller.

---

**If using `--in-place`**, then the operating system will deny write permissions due to the file being in-use (not enforced for all access on UNIX, but specifically enforced with `mmap(MAP_PRIVATE)`, as used for executables and shared libraries); this would be a "Text file busy" error. If your operating system *did not* enforce this, any scenario where `mmap()` were used to provide memory regions reflecting file contents (which is typically how shared libraries are loaded) would cause Bad Things to happen in the event of an in-place overwrite.

Comment: Multiple files isn't an issue per se.  The executables mostly run as daemons and we don't usually overwrite multiple files intra-week.  Thanks for pointing out multiple files thing.  I never expected that to work in the first place if an exported existing function's signature changed